# How can I total multiple rows in a table?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to automatically update the total of each row with jQuery but this is not working properly.

Here is the jQuery code:

```
$('.val1').keydown(function(e) {
    var val1 = this.value;
    var val2 = $('.val2').val();
    var total = val1 * val2;
    $('.equal').val(total);
});
```

Here is the HTML code:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Value 1</th>
      <th>Value 2</th>
      <th>Equal</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="val1" name="val1" type="text" value=""></td>
    <td><input class="val2" name="val2" type="text" value=""></td>
    <td><input class="equal" name="equal" type="text" value=""></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="val1" name="val1" type="text" value=""></td>
    <td><input class="val2" name="val2" type="text" value=""></td>
    <td><input class="equal" name="equal" type="text" value=""></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="val1" name="val1" type="text" value=""></td>
    <td><input class="val2" name="val2" type="text" value=""></td>
    <td><input class="equal" name="equal" type="text" value=""></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You need to realize that class names that are used more than once will be an array.  $('.val2').val(); is meaningless.

Comment: i want to val1 * val2 = update equal automatic of each row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to target everything in context of the `.val1` you're acting on. Here is the code you will want to use:

```
$('.val1').keyup(function(e) {
    var val1 = parseInt($(this).val());
    var val2 = parseInt($(this).parent().siblings('td').find('.val2').val());
    var total = val1 * val2;
    $(this).parent().siblings('td').find('.equal').val(total);
});
```

`.keydown()` was changed to `.keyup()` because the event was firing before `.val1` received a value from the keypress. Since you're multiplying the two values together, I turned both of them into numbers with `parseInt` so that `.equal` doesn't end up with `NaN` as a value.

You can see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/3hqkR/1/

Answer (score 0):

`$('.val2')` will give you an array of ALL elements with this class name.

Therefore `var val2 = $('.val2').val();` will never work.

You need to grab the first element RELATIVE to where the event occurred:

```
var val2 = $(this).prev('tr').find('.val2').val();
```

Comment: `.previous()` is not a jQuery method. Even using the proper `.prev()` coupled with `$(this)`, you would not target `.val2` because it is not a sibling of `.val1`, so this solution will not work at all.